# Ext JS Problem with MultiGroupingStore/MultiGoupingView user extensions

Tags: gridview, extjs, grouping, datastore

I am facing an issue with the MultiGroupingView extension that is used to get more than one level of grouping on grid data...I am using the version posted [on this thread](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?42454-Multiple-level-of-grouping-in-grids&p=279577#post279577). the thing is, whenever i move the mouse over any row on the resulting grid, this error occurs on FireBug:

> gs[i].id.split("gp-")[1] is undefined
>   Line 435 MultiGroupingView.js

I am not able to understand why this is happening. This is the js code I am using:

```
/*
* Ext JS Library 2.2.1
* Copyright(c) 2006-2009, Ext JS, LLC.
* licensing@extjs.com
*
* http://extjs.com/license
*/

Ext.onReady(function(){

  Ext.QuickTips.init();

  var xg = Ext.grid;

  // shared reader
  var reader = new Ext.data.ArrayReader({}, [
     {name: 'company'},
     {name: 'price', type: 'float'},
     {name: 'change', type: 'float'},
     {name: 'pctChange', type: 'float'},
     {name: 'lastChange', type: 'date', dateFormat: 'n/j h:ia'},
     {name: 'industry'},
     {name: 'desc'}
  ]);

  var grid = new xg.GridPanel({
      //This is definition of MultiGroupingStore
       store: new Ext.ux.MultiGroupingStore({
          reader: reader,
          data: xg.dummyData,
          sortInfo:{field: 'company', direction: "ASC"},
          groupField:['industry','lastChange']
      }),

      columns: [
          {id:'company',header: "Company", width: 60, sortable: true, dataIndex: 'company'},
          {header: "Price", width: 20, sortable: true, renderer: Ext.util.Format.usMoney, dataIndex: 'price'},
          {header: "Change", width: 20, sortable: true, dataIndex: 'change', renderer: Ext.util.Format.usMoney},
          {header: "Industry", width: 20, sortable: true, dataIndex: 'industry'},
          {header: "Last Updated", width: 20, sortable: true, renderer: Ext.util.Format.dateRenderer('m/d/Y'), dataIndex: 'lastChange'}
      ],

       //This is definition of MultiGroupingView
       view: new Ext.ux.MultiGroupingView({
                hideGroupedColumn : true
          ,     forceFit                : true
          ,     emptyGroupText          : 'All grouped fields empty!'
          ,     startCollapsed          : true
          ,     groupTextTpl            : '{gvalue}'// ({[values.rs.length]} {[values.rs.length > 1 ? "Items" : "Item"]})'
          ,     displayFieldSeparator: ', '
      }),

      frame:true,
      width: 700,
      height: 450,
      collapsible: true,
      animCollapse: false,
      title: 'Grouping Example',
      iconCls: 'icon-grid',
      renderTo: document.body
  });
});

// Array data for the grids
Ext.grid.dummyData = [
  ['3m Co',71.72,0.02,0.03,'4/2 12:00am', 'Manufacturing'],
  ['Alcoa Inc',29.01,0.42,1.47,'4/1 12:00am', 'Manufacturing'],
  ['Altria Group Inc',83.81,0.28,0.34,'4/3 12:00am', 'Manufacturing'],
  ['American Express Company',52.55,0.01,0.02,'4/8 12:00am', 'Finance'],
  ['American International Group, Inc.',64.13,0.31,0.49,'4/1 12:00am', 'Services'],
  ['AT&T Inc.',31.61,-0.48,-1.54,'4/8 12:00am', 'Services'],
  ['Boeing Co.',75.43,0.53,0.71,'4/8 12:00am', 'Manufacturing'],
  ['Caterpillar Inc.',67.27,0.92,1.39,'4/1 12:00am', 'Services'],
  ['Citigroup, Inc.',49.37,0.02,0.04,'4/4 12:00am', 'Finance'],
  ['E.I. du Pont de Nemours and Company',40.48,0.51,1.28,'4/1 12:00am', 'Manufacturing'],
  ['Exxon Mobil Corp',68.1,-0.43,-0.64,'4/3 12:00am', 'Manufacturing'],
  ['General Electric Company',34.14,-0.08,-0.23,'4/3 12:00am', 'Manufacturing'],
  ['General Motors Corporation',30.27,1.09,3.74,'4/3 12:00am', 'Automotive'],
  ['Hewlett-Packard Co.',36.53,-0.03,-0.08,'4/3 12:00am', 'Computer'],
  ['Honeywell Intl Inc',38.77,0.05,0.13,'4/3 12:00am', 'Manufacturing'],
  ['Intel Corporation',19.88,0.31,1.58,'4/2 12:00am', 'Computer'],
  ['International Business Machines',81.41,0.44,0.54,'4/1 12:00am', 'Computer'],
  ['Johnson & Johnson',64.72,0.06,0.09,'4/2 12:00am', 'Medical'],
  ['JP Morgan & Chase & Co',45.73,0.07,0.15,'4/2 12:00am', 'Finance'],
  ['McDonald\'s Corporation',36.76,0.86,2.40,'4/2 12:00am', 'Food'],
  ['Merck & Co., Inc.',40.96,0.41,1.01,'4/2 12:00am', 'Medical'],
  ['Microsoft Corporation',25.84,0.14,0.54,'4/2 12:00am', 'Computer'],
  ['Pfizer Inc',27.96,0.4,1.45,'4/8 12:00am', 'Services', 'Medical'],
  ['The Coca-Cola Company',45.07,0.26,0.58,'4/1 12:00am', 'Food'],
  ['The Home Depot, Inc.',34.64,0.35,1.02,'4/8 12:00am', 'Retail'],
  ['The Procter & Gamble Company',61.91,0.01,0.02,'4/1 12:00am', 'Manufacturing'],
  ['United Technologies Corporation',63.26,0.55,0.88,'4/1 12:00am', 'Computer'],
  ['Verizon Communications',35.57,0.39,1.11,'4/3 12:00am', 'Services'],
  ['Wal-Mart Stores, Inc.',45.45,0.73,1.63,'4/3 12:00am', 'Retail'],
  ['Walt Disney Company (The) (Holding Company)',29.89,0.24,0.81,'4/1 12:00am', 'Services'] ];

// add in some dummy descriptions
for(var i = 0; i < Ext.grid.dummyData.length; i++){
     Ext.grid.dummyData[i].push('Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Sed metus nibh, sodales a, porta at, vulputate eget, dui. Pellentesque ut nisl. Maecenas tortor turpis, interdum non, sodales non, iaculis ac, lacus. Vestibulum auctor, tortor quis iaculis malesuada, libero lectus bibendum purus, sit amet tincidunt quam turpis vel lacus. In pellentesque nisl non sem. Suspendisse nunc sem, pretium eget, cursus a, fringilla vel, urna.<br/><br/>Aliquam commodo ullamcorper erat. Nullam vel justo in neque porttitor laoreet. Aenean lacus dui, consequat eu, adipiscing eget, nonummy non, nisi. Morbi nunc est, dignissim non, ornare sed, luctus eu, massa. Vivamus eget quam. Vivamus tincidunt diam nec urna. Curabitur velit.'); }
```

This is the relevant part of MultiGroupingView class:

```
Ext.ux.MultiGroupingView = Ext.extend(Ext.grid.GroupingView, {

     [. . . . . . .]

  /** Should return an array of all elements that represent a row, it should bypass
  *  all grouping sections
  */
  getRows: function() {
      var r = [];
      // This function is called many times, so use a cache if it is available
      if (this.rowsCache) {
          r = this.rowsCache;
          //console.debug('View.getRows: cached');
      } else {
          //console.debug('View.getRows: calculate');
          if (!this.enableGrouping) {
              r = Ext.grid.GroupingView.superclass.getRows.call(this);
          } else {
              var groupField = this.getGroupField();
              var g, gs = this.getGroups();
              // this.getGroups() contains an array of DIVS for the top level groups
              //console.debug("Get Rows", groupField, gs);

              r = this.getRowsFromGroup(r, gs, groupField[groupField.length - 1]);
          }
          // Clone the array, but not the objects in it
          if (r.length >= 0) {
              // Don't cache if there is nothing there, as this happens during a refresh
              //@TODO comment this to disble caching, incase of problems
              //this.rowsCache = r;
          } // else  
          //console.debug("No Rows to Cache!");
      }
      //console.debug("View.getRows: Found ", r.length, " rows",r[0]);
      //console.trace();
      return r;
  },
  /** Return array of records under a given group
  * @param r Record array to append to in the returned object
  * @param gs Grouping Sections, an array of DIV element that represent a set of grouped records
  * @param lsField The name of the grouping section we want to count
  */
  getRowsFromGroup: function(r, gs, lsField) {
      var rx = new RegExp(".*-gp-" + lsField + "-.*");
      for (var i = 0, len = gs.length; i < len; i++) {

          if (gs[i].id != "") {
              if (gs[i].id.split('gp-')[1].split('-')[0] == lsField) {
                  g = gs[i].childNodes[1].childNodes;
                  for (var j = 0, jlen = g.length; j < jlen; j++) {

                      r[r.length] = g[j];
                  }
              }
              else {
                  r = this.getRowsFromGroup(r, gs[i].childNodes, lsField);
              }
          }
      }
      return r;
  }


  /** Override the onLoad, as it always scrolls to the top, we only
  *  want to do this for an initial load or reload. There is a new event registered in
  *  the constructor to do this    
  */
 , onLoad: function() { }
 });
```

Finally, this is the html file:

```
<html>
  <head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
  <title>Grid3 Grouping Example</title>

  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../../resources/css/ext-all.css" />

  <!-- GC -->
    <!-- LIBS -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../../adapter/ext/ext-base.js"></script>
    <!-- ENDLIBS -->

  <script type="text/javascript" src="../../ext-all.js"></script>


  <script type="text/javascript" src="grouping.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="MultiGroupingStore.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="MultiGroupingView.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="grid-examples.css" />

  <!-- Common Styles for the examples -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../shared/examples.css" />

  <style type="text/css">
      body .x-panel {
          margin-bottom:20px;
      }
      .icon-grid {
          background-image:url(../shared/icons/fam/grid.png) !important;
      }
      #button-grid .x-panel-body {
          border:1px solid #99bbe8;
          border-top:0 none;
      }
      .add {
          background-image:url(../shared/icons/fam/add.gif) !important;
      }
      .option {
          background-image:url(../shared/icons/fam/plugin.gif) !important;
      }
      .remove {
          background-image:url(../shared/icons/fam/delete.gif) !important;
      }
      .save {
          background-image:url(../shared/icons/save.gif) !important;
      }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../shared/examples.js"></script><!-- EXAMPLES -->
<h1>GridView3 Grouping</h1>
<p>Note that the js is not minified so it is readable. See <a href="grouping.js">grouping.js</a>.</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Any ideas on how this can be fixed?